# MySQL substract rows under same column in same table but with varying primary key

Tags: mysql

I am new to this forum and to the MySQL. My question would be similar to the previous posts however would like to know if this can be solved with code.

I have table in mysql with primary key as id, Month (In date format) and Site Count.
Now I want a table output which contains Month, Site count and difference in between the count calculated from site count.

```
ID    Month         Site Count
1     31-01-2014    37
256   28-02-2014    37
512   31-03-2014    37
768   30-04-2014    41
1024  31-05-2014    38
1280  30-06-2014    42
1536  31-07-2014    42
```

Note: The reason ID is not in order is because it is derived from the main table.
Site count is derived value from the main table count(distinct `site`) as `site count`

Now I want the table to be created as below which can not be calculated using Id field

```
ID   Month      Site Count  Diff
1    31-01-2014    37        0
256  28-02-2014    37        0
512  31-03-2014    37        4
768  30-04-2014    41        2
1024 31-05-2014    43        1
1280 30-06-2014    44        2
1536 31-07-2014    46
```

Last value could not be calculated as there is preceding value 
Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either variables or correlated subqueries/join.  Here is the latter method:

```
select t.id, t.month, t.sitecount, (next_sitecount - sitecount) as diff
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.sitecount
              from t t2
              where t2.month > t.month
              order by month
              limit 1
             ) as next_sitecount
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon for your response, however for some reason I am receiving error at my end. Just for your information sitecount here is calculated field as Count(distinct `site`) and the database_table name is dummystudy.studytrend.
I tried editing the code as suggested but is unable to understand where the error is.. apologies for the inconvenience. :)